# Переход с 1 на 2-ую сцену (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity3d

Пытаюсь сделать игру на Android, при клике по кнопке для перехода на другую сцену выдает ошибку:

> Scene '0211651' couldn't be loaded because it has not been added to the build settings or the AssetBundle has not been loaded.
>   To add a scene to the build settings use the menu File->Build Settings...
>   UnityEngine.Application:LoadLevel(String)
>   Buttons:OnMouseUpAsButton() (at Assets/Scripts/Buttons.cs:11)
>   UnityEngine.SendMouseEvents:DoSendMouseEvents(Int32)

Код для перехода (C#):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Buttons : MonoBehaviour {
    private void OnMouseUpAsButton() {
        switch (gameObject.name) {
            case "Play":
                Application.LoadLevel("0211651");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Может ли это быть из-за того, что сцены делал не в одном проекте, а в двух, а потом уже импортировал из одного в другой?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно проблема в том, что вы не добавили сцену в сборку. Чтобы это сделать нужно поставить галочку напротив нужной сцены в Build Settings